# print enumeration names for a golang list

Tags: go, enums

I have the following enumeration, and its string function.
When I use Println on a specific Animal value, the proper
name is printed. But when I print it as a full list, then
only their integer values are printed.
How to print the animal names when I am printing the zoo-list also?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Animal int64

const (
    Goat Animal = iota
    Cat
    Dog
)

func (n Animal) String() string {
    switch n {
    case Goat:
        return "Goat"
    case Cat:
        return "Cat"
    case Dog:
        return "Dog"
    }
    return "?"
}

type Group struct {
    a, b Animal
}

type Zoo []Group

func main() {
    var g1,g2 *Group
    g1 = new(Group)
    g1.a = Goat
    g1.b = Cat
    g2 = new(Group)
    g2.a = Dog
    g2.b = Cat

    var z1 Zoo
    z1 = []Group{*g1,*g2}

    fmt.Println("Animal: ", Dog) // prints Dog
    fmt.Println(z1) // prints [{0 1} {3 1}]
}
```

Comment: Only by defining `String() string` appropriately on `Group` and then defining the same method on `Zoo`, and both methods should take measues to format their arguments using the `String` methods of the types of its "nested" fields and/or elements. The idea (consider reading the manual page of the `fmt` package; run `go run fmt`) is that `String()` is only looked for on a top-level value passed to printing functions of `fmt`, in certain cases. These functions do not somehow recursively _descend_ into fields/elements of structured and compound types.

Comment: One back-of-the-envelope [approach](https://go.dev/play/p/a0o8orU7uZd).

Comment: `a, b Animal` are private/unexported in the `Group` struct so `GoStringer` reflect magic cannot apply. You can expose them or use `String()` as mentioned above. Technically, only `String()` for Group is needed. https://go.dev/play/p/CtW_mHfyanF

Comment: @greedy52: that is an excellent answer. If you post this, I will accept.

Comment: However, the mechanics of applying the String() func to struct fields is not clear to me. I understand that without CAPS the name is not exported. But then, shouldnt I have got an error that the names are not visible, instead of simply not applying the String() func to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @greedy52 said `a` and `b` should exported (it's the right answer).

But if you want to keep them `private` and have a similar output, just implement the `String()` method on `Group` just like that:

```
func (g Group) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("{%s %s}", g.a, g.b)
}
```